# Adding a column to a table with nonclustered columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore

Adding a column to a table that has a nonclustered columnstore index on it is not a problem, but is it possible to add a column to nonclustered columnstore index itself without dropping it and creating again?

Comment: Have you tried it? You can't add a column to a regular NC index, so...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is added to NCI Column Store index. because all columns of a table are part of Column store index. Reason why doing inserts on a column store index are MUCH SLOWER compared to table on heap or Row based NCI index.

Comment: Yes, but adding a column to a rowstore index is a hard operation due to it’s structure. For columnstore it should be simpler (and it is, for clustered one, it lasts only seconds). Also, I can create a second rowstore index with ONLINE option and remove the old one. Can’t do it with columnstore.

Comment: @junketsu, nope, it is true only for clustered columnstore indexes. NCI does not have to contain all columns of the table

Comment: then there you go. Which would only mean that if you add a new column in. You will have to drop and re-create the NCI-CS index to take into account the new/latest column(s) in question.

Comment: Yes but it can’t be done online, so a downtime of application using it is required :/